# When is $U\times_XU$ isomorphic to $U$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

For topological spaces with $U\times_XV=U\cap V\subset X$, we obviously have $U\times_XU=U\cap U = U$, but for schemes, when is this the case? It looks like it should have something to do with separatedness, but are there some general criterions?

Comment: At the very least, if $U\subseteq X$ is an open subscheme, possibly also a closed subscheme.

Comment: This is precisely the condition that the inclusion of $U$ is a monomorphism in the category of schemes. For a characterization see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56591/what-are-the-monomorphisms-in-the-category-of-schemes .

Comment: @Arthur For closed subschemes, this is just $R/I \otimes_R R/I = R/I$.

Comment: @MooS True, at least locally. I should've seen the monomorphism characterisation, though.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed immediate from the universal property.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured something out from the comments above. One sufficient condition is that the map is mono.

If $U\to X$ is mono, then the pullback $p:U\times_XU\to U$ is.

So obviously, given the identity $1:U\to U$ we get a unique $f:U\to U\times_XU$ by the universal property square. Composing with the natural projection $p$ gives $pf=1$ and thus $pfp=p$. Since $p$ is mono we get $fp=1$ and thus they are isomorphisms.